# Java API Load Testing And Monitoring Toolkit?

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, benchmarking, gatling

I am testing APIs and I would like to load test it with hits/request per second. I would like to measure response time for each request, but I would also like to monitor CPU usage and JVM heap memory as the test is executed.

I found JMeter with perfmon agent to give exactly what I am requesting, but it seems that one has to bend over backwards to maintain the desired RPS and there is always the occasional bug.

I am quite disappointed in that regards, so I am looking for an alternative solution. I have found tools like Gatling but they do not seem to offer JVM monitoring tools with the test. So what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

You should use JMeter plugin 
 [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

> Threads pool size can be calculated like `RPS * <max response time> / 1000`

[image]

Comment: Tried that and reported in another post before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55055046/problems-maintaining-trivial-rps-numbers-with-jmeter-for-api-testing. This is one of the reasons why I indicated that I'm looking for a JMeter alternative.